# How to embedd Qt libraries in a Windows Qt app?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, build

My Qt application is going to be installed on a Windows computer but Qt is not installed on it.

How could I get around this problem? Am I obliged to build a huge static exe?

Is it possible to put Qt DLLs in the same folder as my application and link it to them? I have found this explanation "[Creating the Application Package](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/deployment-windows.html#creating-the-application-package)" on Qt website but it is plugin oriented.

Comment: @IgorR. You will need a commercial license to do that.

Comment: @cmannett85 not true. You can abide by the LGPL if you link statically, but you need to disclose your source or object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to put Qt DLLs in the same folder as my application and
>   link it to them?

Yes, Windows will look for the DLLs in the folder the executable resides in (amongst other [places](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Comment: It won't find the plugins though. The `qt.conf` approach is a must!

Comment: I don't have plugins in my app.

Answer (score 3):

You just put the DLLs in the same directory as your executable and create a qt.conf with the content:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=.\
Plugins=.\
```

This way you ensure that the Qt system will pick up the plugins you might use from the correct directory (for example `sqldrivers` directory for the SQL plugins). Of course, you can customize these paths according to your needs, this is the simplest solution...

Make sure you pick the correct DLL from the Qt directory to which your application links to.